# creating a list of object in groovy

Tags: groovy

Given the fallowing lists, I need to create a list mapping the items of the list:

```
def list1=[math,science]
def list2=[90,80]
```

create `listofObj=[{label:"activity score",value:90},{label:"math",value=80}]`
I've tried `listofObj=[[tablelabels,tablevalues].transpose().collectEntries{[it[0],it[1]]}]`
but it's producing a simple mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is quite close. But the transpose only gives you the
tuples for label/value.  If you need a fresh map with the keys, you have
to create it.  E.g.

```
def labels=["math","science"]
def values=[90,80]

println([labels,values].transpose().collect{ label, value -> [label: label, value: value] })
// → [[label:math, value:90], [label:science, value:80]]
```